# How to prove inequality that involves log?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Can you, please, give me hints on proving the following inequality:

$$\frac{2^{L-1}-2}{2^{L-2}\left(\frac{q}{1-q} + L\right)+2} < \log\left[\frac{2^{L-1} + 2^{L-2}\left(\frac{q}{1-q} + L - 1\right) -1}{2^{L-2}\left(\frac{q}{1-q} + L - 1\right) +1}\right],$$

where $L >3$ is a finite integer and $q \in (0,1)$

Comment: That looks like a monster. Have you even tried wrangling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facing the monster, I should consider $$f(q)=\frac{2^{L-1}-2}{2^{L-2}\left(\frac{q}{1-q} + L\right)+2} - \log\left[\frac{2^{L-1} + 2^{L-2}\left(\frac{q}{1-q} + L - 1\right) -1}{2^{L-2}\left(\frac{q}{1-q} + L - 1\right) +1}\right]$$ and defining $a=\frac q{1-q}$ just focus on $f(a)$ to try to show that $f(a)$ has a maximum value which is negative. Taking derivatives leads (thank you for the fun !) to $$f'(a)=\frac{2^{L+1} \left(2^L-4\right) \left(2^{L+3} (2 a+2
   L-1)+4^L+80\right)}{\left(2^L (a+L-1)+4\right) \left(2^L (a+L)+8\right)^2
   \left(2^L (a+L+1)-4\right)}$$ Hoping no problem with the denominator, the derivative cancels for $$a_*=-L-2^{L-4}-5\times 2^{-L}+\frac{1}{2}$$ which is negative.

Anyway, let us compute $f(a_*)$ $$f(a_*)=-\frac{16}{2^L-12}-\frac{16}{2^L+4}-2 \log \left(2^L-12\right)+2 \log
   \left(2^L+4\right)$$ which is negative for any $L\geq 4$. In fact $f(a_*)$ goes asymptotically to $0$ by negative value.

Using $x=2^L$ and using Taylor expansions and then approximants $$f(a_*)\sim -\frac{1}{3} 2^{3(4- L)}$$

I leave you the pleasure to show it

Comment: You are welcome !

Comment: The extremum that you found is a local minimum; and there is a discontinuity at $a=0$.  Nevertheless, it was helpful to look at the problem via $f(a)$ function

Comment: @Beck. I was just thinking about this and I wanted to make a second derivative test. Believe it or not, $f''(a)$ must be very simple. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Beck. I checked and, effectively, $$f''(a_*)=\frac{2^{2 L+21} \left(2^L-4\right)}{\left(2^L-12\right)^4 \left(2^L+4\right)^4}$$ which is always positive.